# Disable buttons on "Review Suggested Edits" once user reaches limit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When I look through the "Review Suggested Edits" tab, there are always buttons for Approve/Reject/Improve. These buttons appear unless I've already voted to Approve/Reject the suggested edit.

After voting to Approve/Reject an edit, a notice appears which I usually ignore. It often reads either "Waiting on 1 more vote" or "Edit has already been approved/rejected". However, it sometimes reads

> Out of votes - you may only vote 40 times a day.

When this is the case, perhaps instead the system should:

1. Place a banner at the top that reads something like:

   > These edits were suggested by users who have not yet earned full edit
   >   privileges. Approve edits you know are correct; reject those you know
   >   are wrong. Leave ambiguous edits for other users to judge. You may
   >   also view suggested edit stats.
   >
   > **You are out of votes for today; you may only vote 40 times a day.**
2. Disable or remove the Approve/Reject buttons after each suggested edit.

It sometimes takes me a few times to realize that my efforts are wasted. Granted, this is in part because I don't take the time to read the notice, but I still think adding this bit of functionality would be a sociable thing to do.

This goes as well for the "edit(n)" notices on questions/answers that are viewed on the site rather than through this tab.

Comment: `why not just disable or remove the Approve/Reject buttons?` -- Because allowing users to click the button and then providing the message *"Out of votes - you may only vote 40 times a day"* is informative; it teaches people how to use the system. Suddenly dimming the button for no apparent reason is not helpful at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair point. I've revised my suggestion to include a static notice at the top of the screen in addition to disabling the buttons.

Comment: Haven't run into this problem, so no way to test this out, but wouldn't using the "Improve this Edit" functionality to mark the edit as "helpful" (or not mark it helpful) be a way around this limit?